# http.StripPrefix: Serving a file from a custom folder

Tags: go

I'm running main.cgi from this directory:

```
htmlroot/sub/main.cgi
```

A request to the resource might look like this:

```
http://www.mysite/sub/main.cgi
```

My HTML pages include static CSS files, referred to something like this:

```
<link href="/styles/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

However, the static files are actually located here:

```
htmlroot/sub/styles/main.css
```

I'm trying to tell Go to grab the file from the htmlroot/sub/styles instead of htmlroot/styles, but I can't seem to make it work. The code looks like this:

```
styleDir := http.FileServer(http.Dir("styles")) //I think this should point to root/sub/styles -- but maybe not?

http.Handle("/styles/", http.StripPrefix("/styles/", styleDir)
```

In this case, main.css is not found. I believe it's actually looking for it in htmlroot/styles, but I'm not sure why.

I'd appreciate any tips.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
styleDir := http.FileServer(http.Dir("sub"+filepath.Separator+"styles"))
http.Handle("/styles/", http.StripPrefix("/styles/", styleDir)
```